# How to stop bootstrap modal for some time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here i'm using AngularJs code along with Bootstrap here i want to stop Modal for few seconds before it execute next code.

```
 xxer.then(function (msg) {
                    if ($scope.msg = "Your A/c Activated ....") {
                        $scope.msg = msg.data;
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $('#modal2').modal('show')

                        },4000)
                                   $window.location.href = '/Account/Inbox';
```

Before it execute  $window.location.href = '/Account/Inbox'; this code i wana to stop it 4sec please helpme how can i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be other way,

```
xxer.then(function (msg) {
if ($scope.msg = "Your A/c Activated ....") {
   $scope.msg = msg.data;
   $('#modal2').modal('show')
   $timeout(function () {
     $window.location.href = '/Account/Inbox';
},4000)
```